# Next.js - How to show post name in the url instead of the id and make it unique?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, clean-urls, next-router

I searched for this but I could only find examples in Laravel and PHP, and I need to know how to do this with Next.js.

All I know is that I can do dynamic routes in Next.js the usual way like this ...

`/pages/post/[postId]` which will translate to `/pages/post/23435` for example, and that way if someone has the URL I could just grab the `[postId]` with `router.query` and can show the correct post to the user, easy enough.

But what if I want to show the post name in the URL instead of the id? just like what Udemy does with dashes between the words ...

```
https://www.udemy.com/course/your-custom-react-component/learn/lecture/
```

And at the same time if someone has that URL I could still show the correct post to them?

I know I could just do `/pages/post/[postName]` and show the post name in the URL, but that won't be unique, and won't be able to show the correct post.

How can I do that?

Comment: i think that is a param and you can access it like this router.params.postId for query you would add ?postId=23435 and access it like this router.query.postId

Comment: @NaveenKashyap I'm not sure I follow, could you post an example?

Comment: when someone visit /pages/post/[postId] you can get the postId when component mount or created then make a fetch req with postId

Comment: @NaveenKashyap No, I know how to do that already, I need to show the post name instead of the id in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can to do it with `postName` as you propose, and then take care that postNames are unique and that each one maps to a `postId` (that's something you need to deal with on your side; so in your database you would generate a unique slug for each `postName`)

Another solution would be to  show both the name and the id like `/pages/post/[postName]/[postId]`. You can use several params, check https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes